Can Gomoku(five in a row) draw on an infinite board? What about other m,n,k-games?
My question: how to prove or disprove the following two conjectures?
Conjecture 1: (Gomoku large conjecture) there is no draw on infinite board for Gomoku with any initial opening with finite stones, if both players play optimally.
It has been widely believed among Gomoku players. But I have never seen researches on "something cannot draw" for $N$-in-a-row.
Maybe we can start from 3-in-a-row? (2-in-a-row is trivial for any opening)
Conjecture 2: (One famous open problem) $6$-in-a-row on infinite board is a draw.
[Edited May.16.2024] Today I found many researches on this, without solving even $7$-in-a-row. So proving it may be hopeless in a short time.

Updated on 25/5/2024
Trying to solve 7-in-a-row using reinforcement learning
I found this article Towards solving the 7-in-a-row game, which
reduced the problem of proving "7-in-a-row is a draw on infinite board" to a problem of solving $(4, n, 7
^{tr})$–game (defined in the article) which is on a $4×n$ board. If there exists such $n$ that the second player (the breaker) can win the $(4, n, 7
^{tr})$–game, then 7-in-a-row is proved to be a draw.
I trained an AlphaZero-like AI which uses neural networks with reinforcement learning (forked from KataGo) Modified KataGo for solving the $(4, n, 7^{tr})$–game. The training include $n$ from 9 to 31. Although it cannot be a "proof", it is helpful to estimate the min $n$.
Sadly, it shows that the smallest $n$ for the breaker to win is probably around $30$, which means it is almost impossible to solve 7-in-a-row using this method(board size=$4×30$,  $3^{4×30}$ states). New method which is more than just dividing the infinite board to finite parts is probably needed.
The following figure shows the win-rate of the AI of the breaker with different $n$.


Definition of $\mathbf{M},\mathbf{N}, \mathbf{K}$-games and Gomoku ($\mathbf{K}=5$): relevant Wikipedia entry

The following statements are the reasons why I proposed these conjectures.
Background of Gomoku
Gomoku, or Five-in-a-row, is a popular board game worldwidely. Black and white alternatively play one stone. Who first connects five stones straight or diagonally wins.
It is widely known that black (the first player) has a winning strategy for Gomoku (Five in a row). So the professional players are using swap rules: these allow the forming of a "balanced opening", in which both players think neither black nor white has advantage. Then two players start the game from this opening.
Draw-rate vs board-size for Gomoku
For $15\times15$ boards started with balanced openings, the draw rate(the probability of draw) is about $50\%$ for top players or AIs. However, the draw rate drops exponentially when board size increases, $\sim 3\%$ for $19\times 19$ board and $\sim 0.1\%$ for $25\times 25$.
In addition, I found that more and more openings on bigger boards can be "almost-solved" by AI. For example, $F2$, $G2$, and $H2$ openings (openings with just one black stone initially) are three balanced openings for "swap after first move" rule on $15\times 15$ board. However, all of these have big advantages for black with $19\times 19$ board, means there is no balanced openings for "swap after first move" rule.
From this, I have the following conjecture：
Conjecture 1: there is no draw on infinite board for Gomoku, if both players play optimally and the number of the stones of the initial opening is finite.
Which means, either black or white has a winning strategy.
$6$ or more in a row, and the Critical Point of no-draw and draw
If there is no draw for $5$-in-a-row, then if we increase the difficulty of winning, there might be a critical point of no-draw and draw.
Simply increase to 6-in-a-row might be too much. It's very easy for human players to have a draw for 6-in-a-row. However it has not been proved yet. $8$-in-a-row has been proved to draw by Zetters, which is still very far from $6$.
Alphazero-like AI (Katago) can help finding the critical point. Some results for different rules for large boards are listed below

Gomoku/Renju: no draw.
$6$ in a row: very easy draw.
$5$ straight and $6$ diagonal/$6$ straight and $5$ diagonal: easy draw.
Gomoku on Hex board (equal to blocking one diagonal direction): easy draw
Caro(not win if two teriminals of the five stones are blocked): no draw.
Terminal-five(the last move must be the terminal of the five stones): no draw.
Terminal-five + Caro: near critical point.

Conjecture 2: $6$-in-a-row on infinite board is a draw
One extra question: where is the critical point of no-draw and draw?

It's unclear what kind of answer you're expecting. You did a lengthy summary of the state of the art, from which it is obvious that it is not known for which $n$ optimal play results in a draw, and MO is not a place to formulate conjectures. The question “for which values of $n$ is it mathematically proven that optimal play results in a draw, resp. a win for some player?” is a valid one, but if so, you had better track your “citation needed” about $n=8$: where did you get this information from?

Also, since you are posting this to a math forum, one would expect a mathematically precise definition of the game. Not that I expect major difficulties, but it should at least be written in such a way that makes it clear whether it is played on $\mathbb{N}^2$ or $\mathbb{Z}^2$, what “in a row” means, whether the game ends in a draw as soon as $\omega$ turns have been plaid or whether it continues until the entire board is full — this sort of things. And you didn't define “swap rules” so why did you bring them up?

Thanks for your comments. The answer I need is how to prove these conjectures. I will explain these questions more mathematically.

Have you read either Winning Ways or the various Games of No Chance collections? They're perhaps the best starting point for this. AFAIK you may be able to show that 5-in-a-row is a win on a sufficiently large board 'conceptually', but I would expect that to be well explored already and (given the lack of results) to not readily yield to any techniques that we could offer you. Finding the smallest board on which it's a win seems almost guaranteed to be a product of long computer exploration if at all.

More broadly, as Gro-Tsen noted, 'how do I prove these conjectures that have been open for multiple decades' is not likely to garner much in the way of useful information. You could ask 'what strategies have been used to show that similar games are draws?', and TBH I suspect the first answer would be something along the lines of 'Go look at Winning Ways.'

Thanks for recommending the books to me. I have found some results of n-in-a-row in Winning Ways p738~742. But it didn't give any more information except for what I have written here. It just shows the pair-strategy for 9-in-a-row, and it said second player can draw in 8-in-a-row has been proven by Zetters.

An infinite board might well allow a finite initial position that's
a "tactical" forced draw.  I imagine a position where Black has
a winning advantage in one sector but White can (and thus must)
keep delaying the loss by making short threats in another sector;
there may be an initial position for which this produces an infinite chase,
analogous to a ladder in Go (or perpetual check in Chess).

Ladder is one possible way to force a draw. But I have no idea whether there exists such a ladder pattern for 5-in-a-row. Maybe we can try 3-in-a-row first?

Surely not 3 in a row because it takes only two adjacent to make a double threat. Even for 4 in a row it may be too easy to make double threats.  For 5, possibly the best strategy is to find somebody who is already an expert in the game -- for all we know there may already be a known go-moku ladder.

I think a detailed proof of "no opening is a draw for 3or4-in-a-row" may help answering the same question for 5-in-a-row. So how to prove the 3-in-a-row version of "Gomoku large conjecture" more mathematically?
